# Migrating content db's from SQL server 2005 to SQL server 2008

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to migrate content db's, config DB and admin content DB from SQL server 2005 to SQL server 2008. Please let me know the procedure, how can I proceed with very minimal downtime.

Comment: with in 1 or 2 hrs, new environment should be up and running.

Comment: Hello @Kishore , Your feedback is very important 1. Are the below answers didn't helped you? 2. Do you need any further clarifications? if yes, please comment to the provided answers with your clarifications to can help you or edit your question with these clarifications, else please upvote and mark the correct answer that helped you as accepted to **close this question.** Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To move SharePoint databases to different SQL server, the main steps as below:

1. Detatch the content, config and other related database from your SQL
   2005 instance
2. Take copy of mdf and ldf files for these database
3. Move the mdf and ldf files to the SQL 2012
4. Attach the databases to SQL 2012
5. Re-run the SP 2010 configuration wizard

To get more detailed information, check the article: [Moving SharePoint to a different SQL server](https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=255)